# How to import function in parent folder without importing sys?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am trying to import functions from a file inside a folder linked to a parent folder of the file I'm currently in. To clarify, here is the schema of my folders:

```
/root
  /Math
    linear_algebra.py
  /Algorithms
    gradient_descent.py
```

Inside the *gradient_descent.py* file, I want to import a function **Vector** which is within the *linear_algebra.py* file. I tried that using:

```
from ..Math.linear_algebra import Vector
```

But I get the error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is there any way to make this import **without using another import**, such os or sys?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194143/3155240 - also apparently `...` is supported to go up 2 directories.

Comment: I wanted to use these sub-modules as a way to better organize all my functions by categories (math, statistics, algorithms, etc). Is there a better way to make this organization functional?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
> module. Since the name of the main module is always `"__main__"`,
> modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application
> must always use absolute imports.

You're not supposed to run sub-modules as the main module directly when they contain relative imports. If so, you need some hack. (adding paths to `sys.path` and change the value of `__package__` or etc).

But here is a solution without importing `sys` (or using `PYTHONPATH` environment variable - which basically adds the path to the `sys.path`):

1. change your directory to the parent of `root` folder.
2. run your script from there using `-m` option:

```bash
python -m root.Algorithms.gradient_descent
```

This resolves the `from ..Math.linear_algebra import Vector` import in `gradient_descent.py` module.

**note**: there is no `.py` at the end.